# Related unicode characters are displayed in different sizes or appear misaligned on OS X

Tags: macos, fonts, unicode

I am using a CMS. The special characters `&#x25C1;`(◁) and `&#x25B7;`(▷) do look far smaller on a Mac than on a Windows system (both Firefox).
`&#x25B3;`(△) and `&#x25Bd;`(▽) looks fine though.

> [image]

I already changed the font-family because I thought the reason could be problem with the font, but even using Helvetica, Western or even Tahoma and Arial those characters are small.
This looks to me like a very special Mac OS or Firefox thing.

Does anyone have an idea why that is so and what can be done?

Comment: I fixed this for you, added an example screenshot and [filed a bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109262/unicode-entities-are-shown-in-preview-but-not-in-the-post). As you can see, for me the left arrow also looks smaller (on OS X 10.6)

Comment: @slhck: thanks, this looks far better now. Where did you file a bug report (mac or firefox or even Safari)?

Comment: No, not for any browser, just for the editor here (see the link)! Maybe you can add a better screenshot?

Comment: Ah, ok. But i guess the error is not located in any rte. I am using tinymce - that's the palce where i found this behaviour, but the problem seems to be more underlying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glyphs are just taken from different fonts. Like ◁ could be from Lucida Grande and ▷, △, and ▽ from Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN.

None of the bundled versions of Helvetica, Arial, or Tahoma have any of those glyphs. Some fonts that have all of them are Arial Unicode MS, DejaVu Sans, and Lucida Sans Unicode.

It's the same problem as with sparklines like ▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█. Sometimes the full height or half height glyphs are taken from a different font, so they look misaligned.

Comment: that is a very good description of the problem - and now i know how to solve it (looks like i will have to create a new font)

Comment: Or just add some unicode fonts to your font stack... `<span style="font-family: Helvetica, 'DejaVu Sans', 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif">◁▷△▽</span>`

Comment: that is a good idea

Comment: I'm seeing the _same problem_ in this question and answer, _7 years later_!